# How to do code analysis for particular shelveset in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, tfs, code-analysis, shelveset

Kindly sugest a way to do code analysis of a particular shelvset (or only checked out / modified code) in visual studio. 
No luck using google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TFS build, run the code analysis on the MS Build task and queue the build for specific shelveset.

- Create an empty TFS Build, add MS Build Task and put the argument: `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true`
  [image]
- Queue the build and choose a Shelveset.
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

You could either request review for a pending change or find the particular shelveset and then request review. check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Correct. But before request to review someone, i just want to run code analysis myself for pendig changes or shelvset.

Comment: In VS, you can only run code analysis manually on a project or the solution by default, on the `Analyz`e menu, click `Run Code Analysis` on*ProjectName*. You can check this extension to see whether it meets your requirement: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2017&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr52fu8_a3AIV04yPCh12gw7WEAAYASAAEgLoLfD_BwE